# CAS Login URL giving java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: websphere, saml, cas, spring-saml

CAS Version: 3.5.2,

The CAS WAR Is deployed successfully on IBM WebSphere server and able to generate tickets and validate the same using,
/cas-server-webapp-3.5.2/serviceValidate
/cas-server-webapp-3.5.2/v1/tickets.

But when I hit /cas-server-webapp-3.5.2/login from web browser the below error gets logged in the logs,

value [null].
2020-10-09 10:27:00,510[WebContainer : 0] DEBUG org.jasig.cas.aspect.LogAspect (WebUtils.java:61) - Leaving method [getService] with return value [null].
2020-10-09 10:27:00,511[WebContainer : 0] DEBUG org.jasig.cas.services.web.ServiceThemeResolver (ServiceThemeResolver.java:61) - Leaving method [resolveThemeName] with return value [null].
2020-10-09 10:27:00,512[WebContainer : 0] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag (RequestContextAwareTag.java:86) - null
2020-10-09 10:27:00,516java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1240)
at org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.SamlService.createServiceFrom_aroundBody4(SamlService.java:114)
at org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.SamlService.createServiceFrom_aroundBody5$advice(SamlService.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.SamlService.createServiceFrom(SamlService.java:1)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.SamlArgumentExtractor.extractServiceInternal_aroundBody0(SamlArgumentExtractor.java:36)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.SamlArgumentExtractor.extractServiceInternal_aroundBody1$advice(SamlArgumentExtractor.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.SamlArgumentExtractor.extractServiceInternal(SamlArgumentExtractor.java:1)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.extractService_aroundBody0(AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.java:62)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.extractService_aroundBody1$advice(AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.extractService(AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.java:1)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.WebUtils.getService_aroundBody4(WebUtils.java:68)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.WebUtils.getService_aroundBody5$advice(WebUtils.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.WebUtils.getService(WebUtils.java:1)
at org.jasig.cas.services.web.ServiceThemeResolver.resolveThemeName_aroundBody0(ServiceThemeResolver.java:59)
at org.jasig.cas.services.web.ServiceThemeResolver.resolveThemeName_aroundBody1$advice(ServiceThemeResolver.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.services.web.ServiceThemeResolver.resolveThemeName(ServiceThemeResolver.java:1)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getTheme(RequestContextUtils.java:151)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getTheme(RequestContext.java:318)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag.getMessageSource(ThemeTag.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.resolveMessage(MessageTag.java:193)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
at com.ibm._jsp._casGenericSuccess._jspx_meth_spring_theme_0(_casGenericSuccess.java:180)
at com.ibm._jsp._casGenericSuccess._jspService(_casGenericSuccess.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:220)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:50)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:187)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.ViewFactoryActionAdapter.doExecute(ViewFactoryActionAdapter.java:40)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.EndState.doEnter(EndState.java:100)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.Framewo
[09-10-2020 10:27:00:520 WEST] 000003f4 SystemOut     O   rkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody2(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:128)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody3$advice(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:1)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)

[09-10-2020 10:27:00:522 WEST] 000003f4 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [/WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/casGenericSuccess.jsp] in application [cas-server-webapp-3_5_2_war]. Exception created : [java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1240)
at org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.SamlService.createServiceFrom_aroundBody4(SamlService.java:114)
at org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.SamlService.createServiceFrom_aroundBody5$advice(SamlService.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.SamlService.createServiceFrom(SamlService.java:1)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.SamlArgumentExtractor.extractServiceInternal_aroundBody0(SamlArgumentExtractor.java:36)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.SamlArgumentExtractor.extractServiceInternal_aroundBody1$advice(SamlArgumentExtractor.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.SamlArgumentExtractor.extractServiceInternal(SamlArgumentExtractor.java:1)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.extractService_aroundBody0(AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.java:62)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.extractService_aroundBody1$advice(AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.extractService(AbstractSingleSignOutEnabledArgumentExtractor.java:1)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.WebUtils.getService_aroundBody4(WebUtils.java:68)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.WebUtils.getService_aroundBody5$advice(WebUtils.java:57)
at org.jasig.cas.web.support.WebUtils.getService(WebUtils.java:1)

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue?

Comment: Do you have the latest fixpack installed on your WebSphere Application Server?  I see several APARs that have StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in their abstract.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/715559#9053

Comment: The IBM wepsphere version is WebSphere [IBMJAVA7 7.0.9.0 cf061521.02]Platform 8.5.5.7. But the same setup is working in other environments.